# How to use the correct Google OpenID url to login to my site?

Tags: openid, google-openid

I am trying to implement OpenID as one preferred option to my next web app [here](http://mindinscription.net/webapp/bufferoverrun/index.php)

The code is taken from [this tutorial](http://www.magiclogix.com/blog/webdevelopment/implementing-signon-using-open-id-login-php-and-mysql/) and works if I use my openID from myopenid.com

However, I believe most people would just love to use their everyday email address as their openID, as far as I know, Google, Yahoo, and some other big players have already done this in their systems.

My question is: how could I find the correct "url" to enter in the form to login?
I used my Google OpenID account for StackOverflow and it works just fine. I try to copy my 
openID like this:

```
www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=aitoawllano10bzdzp3ht0diffry0qt6_j2ls-m
```

And paste it directly into my form, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to remove the url parameter, but that won't do, either.

Thanks a lot in advance for any tips and suggestions.

Comment: This would be a good place to start with http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Comment: @Amarghosh : indeed. I didn't know Google explains his way of doing OpenID there. Thanks for this reference!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basically, you're not allowed to use a token produced for one site to authenticate to another. This is a security feature. (OK, the site which is allowed to see the OpenID identity could make an assertion accepted by the other site about your identity, but that's out-of-band w.r.t. OpenID.)

The URL you should use is just this:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
```

Comment: @Donal Fellows : I see. security is the part that makes my head aching all the time. I will read the doc Amarghosh just posted and see if I can get this done myself.