# How to restrict OpenID login to one Google Apps Domain on GAE (again)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-openid

I want to restrict login to a python application running on Google App Engine to members of a particular Google Apps Domain using OpenID.

According to the thread [How limit Google Federated Login to specific Apps domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983934/how-limit-google-federated-login-to-specific-apps-domain) 
this could be accomplished by simply substitution the ordinary google openid autentication url

> https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

with

> https://google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com

This does however not seem to work using users.create_login_url() in GAE for Python. It throws a 500 server error that is not shown in the google app engine log (the log only shows the redirect and the "OpenID" from logging.debug).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

app.yaml

```
application: example
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: main.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app
  login: required
```

main.py:

```
import webapp2, logging
from google.appengine.api import users

# Any google account, works like a charm
#federated_identity='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'

# only accounts under spefific domain, does not work
federated_identity='https://google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com'

dest_url = 'http://example.appspot.com/'

class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.debug('Main')
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            self.response.out.write('Hello %s<p>[<a href="%s">log out</a>]' %  (user.email(),
                    users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)))
        else:
            self.response.out.write('Not logged in')

class OpenID(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        logging.debug('OpenID')
        login_url = users.create_login_url(dest_url=dest_url,
            federated_identity=federated_identity)
        self.redirect(login_url)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/_ah/login_required', OpenID),
    ('/', Main)
], debug=True)
```

**Update**
Sebastian suggests that a solution might be to url encode the federated identity. I tried url encoding the whole url or only the question mark as suggested.  Unfortunately this does not change anything. 
The redirect urls as shown in the browser address bar or if written to log:

No url encoding:
http://example.appspot.com/_ah/login_redir?claimid=https://google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com&continue=http://example.appspot.com/

With url encoding:
http://example.appspot.com/_ah/login_redir?claimid=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fsite-xrds%3Fhd%3Dexample.com&continue=http://example.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (I haven't tested this myself) that the issue is because the federated_identity is not encoded. Try replacing the question mark with `%3F`. Also make sure the url

```
https://google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com
```

works.

The test I did was to go to the url

```
http://testsk2012.appspot.com/_ah/login_redir?claimid=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds%3Fhd=somesite.com&continue=http://testsk2012.appspot.com/
```

and it succeeded.

Comment: Thanks but replacing the "?" with "%3F" makes no difference. I have testet that the url works in the browser so this looks like it has something to do with GAE's inner workings.

Comment: Did you try both urls? Also, can you post how the generated login url looks like?

Comment: Strangely it works with the url https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com but not with https://google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com. There's even no need to urlencode it.

Comment: I did not quite get your last comment Sebastian - your two urls seems to be identical?

Comment: The first one has www. before google.com ( it's the rendering that is hiding that part).

Comment: Now it's "Error: Server Error" on "http://testsk2012.appspot.com/_ah/login_redir?c..." How to fix this?