# Questions to allow Google Federated Login for a specific domain?

Tags: php, google-api, openid, single-sign-on, google-openid

I am new to OpenID and have been requested to build a login system to work with the company's Google account. They want to restrict logins to users of their domain. They login into Gmail using their domain and they want this feature to allow access to their systems.

Let's say the domain is example.com. They would log into Gmail as user@example.com or go to their domain login page to access their accounts.

I have been doing some research and it seems that the [Google Federated Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) is what I should be working with. I downloaded the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) and have been playing with the examples but I still cannot get it to restrict access to whom logs in. Currently anyone with a google account seems to be able to login. Also, the API wants to access certain information... I only want to authenticate the user to ensure they are a valid user of the domain and eventually allow SpreadSheet Access in Google Docs so that another script (in the same system) can create SpreadSheets while the user is updating the system.

So my questions are:

1) Which service do I need to enable in the Google API console? `Enterprise License Manager API` is the only service that is enabled.... I'm starting to think maybe I should disable it.. Do any services have to be enabled? I'm not really sure about this.

2) Is there anything special about the PHP Google APIs that would require me to use Google's API or is this functionality available with any OpenID library? If the latter, which libraries are good for what I am trying to accomplish? (PHP)

3) I have found a few examples for allowing login with a Google account but I haven't found a single one for restricting it to a single domain. I am sure this is possible but am starting to feel that it's very difficult to implement... Any information on this would be very beneficial.

Thanks for any information you can toss my way.

Comment: Did you find anything of the sort? I'm also looking to implement this mechanic and am in a similar boat.

Comment: I put this off until later in the project so I have not found the solution yet. I did see this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983934/how-limit-google-federated-login-to-specific-apps-domain) and it seems to be a step in the right direction. Just remember if you are using the Google API it needs PHP 5.3+. I am stuck on PHP 5.2 so I will have to find an alternative. Let me know if you figure this out

Comment: Unless I find a better alternative, simpleSAMLphp is the route we're likely headed:
http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.5/simplesamlphp-googleapps